# filter list of entities using spring specification

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-stream, filtering, specifications

can I use spring specification to filter list of entities beside the retrived entities form the database

I have a static class that has all the specifications that i use to filter

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Specifications<T> {

    private final Root<T> root;
    private final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
    public void addFamilyFilter(Long familyId, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, List<Predicate> predicates) {
        if (familyId != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("family", JoinType.LEFT).get("id"), familyId));
        }
    }

    public void addStreetFilter(Long streetId, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, List<Predicate> predicates) {
        if (streetId != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("street", JoinType.LEFT).get("id"), streetId));
        }
    }

    public void addNamePartFilter(String namePart, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, List<Predicate> predicates) {
        if (namePart != null) {
            Expression<String> fullName = criteriaBuilder.concat(
                    criteriaBuilder.concat(root.get("firstName"), " "),
                    root.get("lastName")
            );
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(fullName, "%" + namePart + "%"));
        }
    }
}
```

and i use this class to filter the entities form the database

```java
public class YouthSpecificationImpl implements YouthSpecification {

    private YouthFiltersDTO youthFiltersDTO;

    private Specifications<Youth> specifications;

    public YouthSpecificationImpl(YouthFiltersDTO youthFiltersDTO) {
        this.youthFiltersDTO = youthFiltersDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Youth> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        specifications = new Specifications<>(root, criteriaBuilder);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional.ofNullable(youthFiltersDTO)
                .ifPresent(filters -> {
                    specifications.addFamilyFilter(filters.getFamilyId(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates);
                    specifications.addStreetFilter(filters.getStreetId(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates);
                    specifications.addNamePartFilter(filters.getNamePart(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates);
                    specifications.addYearFilter(filters.getYear(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates, "dayOfBirth");
                    specifications.addMonthFilter(filters.getMonth(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates,"dayOfBirth");
                    specifications.addGenderFilter(filters.getGender(), root, criteriaBuilder, predicates);
                });
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

now i want to use the same classes and methods to filter list of `Youths` instead of repeating the same logic
is it possible if yes then how
if not then what is the best solution for my problem

I tried to use this

```
List<Youth> filtered = attendanceList.stream()
                .filter(entity -> specification.toPredicate(null,null, null).equals(entity))//.test(entity))
                .toList();
```

but if fails and say that the parameter of `toPredicate must not be null`